# Doxygen custom tag with a placeholder

Tags: c, doxygen, requirements

Is it somehow possible in Doxygen to create a custom tag, which creates a documentation using a placeholder tag as its input?

What I want to accomplish is to create a custom tag for requirements. As our DOORS Urls are quite long, and diverge from SW-component to SW-component, I want to create something similar to this:

```
@file somefile.c
@doorsdocurl <URL to DOORS document> -> this is going to be my placeholder

...
...
...


/**
* @brief somedescription
* @req{doorsdocurl: <reqID1, reqID2,...> } -> this is going to be the second custom tag
*/
void jambo()
{
}
```

Is this somehow achievable with Doxygen? From what I have read, one has to put his custom tags within the ALIASES variable

Comment: When I understand it correctly you want to set in a file the URL and use this further in this document. Depending on the number of SW components (and the rate the URL changes) I would define an ALIAS per SW component like `doorsdocurl_sw_1=....` and in the `\req` I would use the relevant ALIAS like `\doorsdocurl_sw_1`. Would did be feasible or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Hi @albert. You understood me correctly :) Can you give me a full example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Doxyfile you would need something like:

```
ALIASES = "doorsdocurl_sw_1=<URL to DOORS document>" \
          "req{2}=\1 \2<br>"
```

and the code would look like:

```
/**
* @brief somedescription
*
* @req{@doorsdocurl_sw_1,reqID1}
* @req{@doorsdocurl_sw_1,reqID2}
*/
void jambo()
{
}
```

The `\req` command can of course be extended with other commands, in this respect the command `xrefitem` might be useful, see the manual (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem)

Comment: That's great. Is it somehow also possible to chain req. ids? `@req{@doorsdocurl_sw_1,reqID1,reqID2,..}`

Comment: Yes this is possible you can define multiple `req` aliases like `ref{2}=...`, `req{3}=...` where you handle the different number of arguments.